# Dynamically replace a result value based on given array set

Tags: mysql, sql, select

```
$colors = ['#D23SSD','#UYH441','#FFFFFF'];

//sample user data [1,'ramees@yopmail.com','rameez',2]

DB::table('users')->select('id','email','name','color')->get();
```

So my point here is for some reason on DB I'll be saving the array index of $colors. But on fetching it's obvious I'll get 'color' as the array index. Is there any way I can fetch the array value and select along with the other data.

I don't want to run a loop and insert value also I don't want to use eloquent. I know with eloquent I can define an attribute option and get data. I don't want to use that. I want this to handle with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [ELT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_elt). It accepts multiple arguments, an integer followed by N other arguments. It uses the first integer to index into the following arguments, and returns that one.

Here's how you could use it in MySQL syntax:

```
SELECT id, email, name, ELT(color, '#D23SSD', '#UYH441', '#FFFFFF') AS color
FROM users
```

So where `color` is 2, it'll return '#UYH441'.

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to [pass a raw expression in Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions).

Answer (score 0):

Is this laravel? What does the below give you?

```
$results = DB::table('users')->select('id','email','name','color')->get();
dd($results);
```